# Why can't I execute pubmex.py python script via the automator workflow?

Tags: python, macos, zsh, automator, macos-monterey

I'm trying to execute a python script via the macOS Automator by selecting first files and then calling the Automator workflow from my finder as can be seen in the image below. [image]

the python file I'm trying to execute is a script that is supposed to change the file name of journal articles to a standardized format. [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mmagnus/pubmex)

Why is it that I'm receiving the following errors when trying to use the python script on pdf files via an Automator workflow?

#### It seems that when using the Automator installations that come with the pubmex the pubmex.py can not be found.

```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        pubmex.py $f
    done
```

#### The following error is displayed:

`The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “zsh:3: command not found: pubmex.py”`

#### When specifying the direct location of just the pubmex.py file another error occures.

```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        /users/suntim/miniforge3/bin/pubmex.py $f
    done
```

#### The following error is displayed:

`The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “”`

#### When specifying the direct location of python and the pubmex.py file another error occures.

```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        /usr/local/bin/python3 /users/suntim/miniforge3/bin/pubmex.py $f
    done
```

#### The following error is displayed:

`The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “Traceback (most recent call last): File "/users/suntim/miniforge3/bin/pubmex.py", line 27, in <module> from Bio import Entrez ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'”`

I have all dependencies installed `pip3 install pubmex`, `pip3 install biopython`, `brew install poppler`. As it says in the readme.md that biopython should be isntalled via brew I assume that was a mistake. I instead installed it via pip3.

The same error messages occure regardless of using the zsh or bash version.

Comment: The `Run Shell Script` action runs with a default shell, which does not use any of your environment settings, such as `$PATH`.

Comment: @red_menace do u have a book or other source where I can read more about this?

Comment: It would be similar to AppleScript’s `do shell script`, which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-MY_COMMAND_WORKS_FINE_IN_TERMINAL__BUT_WHEN_I_TRY_TO_USE_IT_IN_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT__I_GET_AN_ERROR_ABOUT____COMMAND_NOT_FOUND______WHAT___S_GOING_ON_).